# FIXED: PostgresSQL Db not updating - Entity Framework - SaveChanges Method could not be found

Tags: c#, postgresql, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been creating a basic CRUD application to add user values to a Db using Entity Framework Core and Postgres.

I have injected my Db Context class into the class where I want to add model data to the table and I can't get it to update.

Here is my Create User Class:

```
using MyApp.Data;
using MyApp.Models;
using static MyApp.Constants.BaseUserConstants;

namespace MyApp.Logic.Users.CreateUserCommand
{
    public class CreateUserCommand : ICreateUserCommand 
    {
       
        private readonly ILogger<CreateUserCommand> _logger;
        private readonly IAppDbContext _appDbContext;

        public CreateUserCommand(ILogger<CreateUserCommand> logger, IStandardApplicationUser standardApplicationUser, IAppDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _appDbContext = appDbContext;

        }

        public int CreateUser(string firstName, string lastName, string email, int age, string bio)
        {

            _appDbContext.StandardApplicationUser.Add(
                new StandardApplicationUser
                {
                    FirstName = firstName,
                    LastName = lastName,
                    Email = email,
                    Age = age,
                    Bio = bio

                }
            );

            _appDbContext.SaveChanges(); //This is method cannot be found!

            return StatusCodes.Status200OK;
        }
    }
}
```

Db Context Class and interface class:

```
using MyApp.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace MyApp.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext, IAppDbContext
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public AppDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            // connect to postgres with connection string from app settings
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"));
        }

        public DbSet<StandardApplicationUser> StandardApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using MyApp.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
namespace MyApp.Data
{
    public interface IAppDbContext
    {
        DbSet<StandardApplicationUser> StandardApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Tried installing other versions of EF package, though this could be the issue. No change in outcome

Answer (score 0):

FIXED! Wasn't exposing SavedChanges in my interface... Silly mistake